# Existence of unbiased estimator for any $f(X)$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator

Suppose you are handed a function of a random variable $f(X)$, how would you construct/rule out the existence of an unbiased estimator for it?

I've read through [Halmos (1946)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-17/issue-1/The-Theory-of-Unbiased-Estimation/10.1214/aoms/1177731020.full) but the characterization was quite a trivial one, almost just a definition.

Comment: We have a couple thousand posts about this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=unbiased+estimator.  For questions about their existence see [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=unbiased+estimator+exist*), which limits the material to only a few hundred posts. It will quickly become apparent that *functions* do not have unbiased estimators: only the function *applied to a random variable assumed to come from a specified family of distributions* has any possibility of having an estimator.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity. I have edited my post. Thank you for those links but none of those answer my question about the existence unbiased estimators for generic functions of random variables. For example we know that f(X) = Var(X) has an unbiased estimator.

Comment: The reason that none of those provide a general answer is that no general answer exists.  The presence of literally hundreds of posts giving a wide array of solutions in special cases is testament to that.